# What's the convention for prefixing categories with magic words?

Tags: objective-c, categories

Convention with categories is to include a prefix when extending Apple classes. For example:

```
[string XXDataUsingUTF8];
```

(Yes, it's a stupid example. Just go with it.)

What I'm less clear on is what the convention is when the identifier starts with `copy`, `set`, `init` or `new`.

For instance:

```
[request setHTTPBodyWithKeyValues: keyValues];
```

If I add my prefix, this no longer follows the "setters start with set" convention.

```
[request XXSetHTTPBodyWithKeyValues: keyValues];
```

On the other hand, if I add the prefix after the set, it's no longer really a prefix:

```
[request setXXHTTPBodyWithKeyValues: keyValues];
```

This isn't terribly import with `set`, but I think it becomes more important with `init`, `copy`, etc.

Has Apple documented this anywhere? What's in common use?

Comment: I've not seen any official guidelines on this, but in the interests of not confusing ARC or the LLVM static analyser, or any other tools or humans reading your code, I'd opt for keeping the conventional prefix intact at the start of the selector. Personally, I use an underscore in category extension method names, as "real" methods never contain one, thus preserving the uniqueness of the "prefix". In your example that would be `setXX_HTTPBodyWithKeyValues:`. In non-convention-based extension methods, that just becomes `XX_myMethodName`.

Comment: I guess this is really the only *practical* answer, isn't it? Thanks for pointing out the obvious. :)

Comment: Very interesting point! Some people like to postfix their "namespace" string: `setHTTPBodyWithKeyValues_XX:` which isn't any prettier.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could set the method family explicitly in the interface declaration:

```
@interface NSObject (StevenFisherCategory)

- (NSData *)XXCopyDataUsingUTF8 __attribute__((objc_method_family(copy)));

@end
```

Comment: This is an excellent point. This is definitely the approach to use going forward with Xcode 4.3 and later using LLVM, especially with ARC.

Comment: Great answer. Was trying to figure out how to get my prefixed init method to work. ```__attribute__((objc_method_family(init)))``` did the trick